# Can't configure URL in Django

Tags: django, django-urls, urlconf

In my `views.py` I have the following code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world!")

def show_day(request):
    return HttpResponse("The day is: test123")
```

and in my `urls.py` in the application folder, I have:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^/show_day/$', views.show_day, name='show_day'),

)
```

now, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myApp` does return the `index()` view, but
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/myApp/show_day` doesn't, but rather gives a 404 error.

What am I doing wrong? Is the problem with the regex in the URLconf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unnecessary leading slash in the second URL. It should be

```
url(r'^show_day/$', views.show_day, name='show_day'),
```

Answer (score 1):

In urls.py, remove the leading slash ('/') from the show_day regex:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    # Don't lead with a slash!
    url(r'^show_day/$', views.show_day, name='show_day'),
)
```